# how to write this sql query to codeigniter query

Tags: codeigniter

SELECT 1 + (SELECT count( * ) FROM student_rank a WHERE a.obtained_total_mark > b.obtained_total_mark ) AS rank FROM student_rank b WHERE student_id = '5' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1 ;

convert search query

Comment: Did you check the CodeIgniter manual?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$this->db->query("SELECT 1 + (SELECT count( * ) FROM student_rank a WHERE a.obtained_total_mark > b.obtained_total_mark ) AS rank FROM student_rank b WHERE student_id = '5' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1")
```